# Oracle-APEX Validation Rules for Empty, half empty & full data fields

Tags: oracle, validation, oracle-apex

So I'm writing up 3 validation rules for CV_DATE_SUBMITTED & CV_DATE_APPROVED

The 1st Validation rule I want to do is set it so that when both fields are empty and the user presses create, it will ignore the validation because both fields are empty.

The 2nd validation rule will be set up so if the user has entered data into the CV_DATE_SUBMITTED field but not for the CV_DATE_APPROVED field because they don't have data for that as yet. When the user presses the create button, it will validate that the CV_DATE_SUBMITTED should be on a date before the present day.

Finally, the 3rd validation rule is set up so if the user has data for both the CV_DATE_SUBMITTED & CV_DATE_APPROVED fields, then it will check that the CV_DATE_APPROVED field cannot be a date after & including the current date, whilst also checking that the CV_DATE_SUBMITTED is not a date after the CV_DATE_APPROVED.

I've managed to complete the 3rd validation rule in the form of CV_DATE_SUBMITTED field having the SQL Expression of  `TO_DATE(:P19_CV_DATE_SUBMITTED) <= TRUNC(SYSDATE)`

And CV_DATE_APPROVED field having the SQL Expression of 
`TO_DATE(:P19_CV_DATE_APPROVED)>= TO_DATE(:P19_CV_DATE_SUBMITTED)`

But I have no idea as to how I can implement the 1st & 2nd validation rules & to get them to work with each other.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to have separate validations that are conditional - only executing when the relevant field is empty/or filled in.

Or have few boolean operations

```
TO_DATE(:P19_CV_DATE_SUBMITTED) <= TRUNC(SYSDATE) or :P19_CV_DATE_SUBMITTED is null
```

And/or you need to learn about [null related](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions002.htm#CJAFHIFF) functions.